# How to show that $¬p→(q→r)$ and $q→(p∨r)$ are logically equivalent using laws?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

It's been an hour and I just can't seem to figure it out. Can anyone enlighten me?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

associative law, $ \neg( \neg p) \equiv p$ and
$$
p \rightarrow q \equiv \neg p \lor q \tag{1}
$$
is enough .
\begin{align}
\neg p \rightarrow (q \rightarrow r) &\equiv \neg \,(\neg p) \lor(q \rightarrow r) \tag{using 1}\\ &\equiv  p \lor(\neg q \lor r) \tag{using 1}\\ \tag{associative}
&\equiv \neg q \lor(p \lor r) \\ 
&\equiv q \rightarrow (p \lor r) \tag{using 1}
\end{align}